# dynamically select sheet from the inputprompt and print to a file

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

i have 3 sheets in my workbook namely sheet1 ,sheet3 and sheet2 when i enter a values from in the inputpromt say (eg:1,2 ) i split it and store it in an array it  must dynamically select the sheet1 and sheet2 and print values to a file.
i have done a pseudo below can any one

```
    Sub example()
Dim Ran As Range
Dim cnt as String

Open "D:\temp\test.txt" For Output As #1
Dim myarray() As String
Dim holder As String
dim ab as Strig
ab="this is sample data"
holder = InputBox("Enter your choice eg:1,2")
myarray = Split(holder, ",")
Dim name, country,birth As String
For i = 1 To UBound(myarray)
If i = 1 Or i = 2 Then
name = Sheets(i).Range("Z12").Value
country= Sheets(i).Range("PQ26").Value
 birth = Sheets(i).Range("ab24").Value
  ab=ab & name & country & birth
    Print #1, ab
End If
Next i
end Sub
```

****in the inputbox if i give value as 1,2 then it must select values from sheet 1 and sheet2****

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to select different ranges on different sheets dependant on what the input is? Eg if i = 1 then sheets(1).range("A1"), if i = 2 then sheets(2).range("b56") ??

Comment: Ya dependent on input eg.: when I=1 then sheets(1).range("a1") .value and sheets(1).range("b56") .value  and when I=2  then sheets(2).range("a1") .value and sheets(2).range("b56") .value

Comment: I agree it is unclear what you are asking.  However `For i = 1 To UBound(myarray)` is wrong.  `Split` creates an array with a lower bound of 0.

Comment: try replacing Sheets(i) with Sheets(i + 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you that you are trying to understand InputBox and how to split a string such as “1, 2” and process the separate values as sheet numbers.

Sheet numbers mean nothing to the user so I do not believe this is a good approach.  You need to offer the user a list of worksheet tabs from which they can select.

There is `InputBox` and `Application.InputBox`.  These are different and I do not like either.  They come from the earliest versions of VB and were probably originally a direct match to MS-DOS’s console input.  With one exception, there are much better approaches.  The one exception is the ability to input a range with `Application.InputBox` for which I do not know a convenient alternative.

In the code below I use `InputBox`.  You may think I have overdone the validation but what if the user enters “A”?  Your code would assume “A” was a sheet number but Excel would assume it was a worksheet name and stop execution with a subscript error.  You must check for any error that will cause your code to stop with a run-time error.

Instead of either `InputBox` you should use a User Form.  There are on-line tutorials to get you started.  With a User Form you have several choices including:

- A List box, with multiple selection enabled, containing the names of every permitted worksheet.
- A column of radio buttons, one per permitted worksheet.  These would be unlinked so the user could select several.
- A command button for each permitted worksheet which the user could click in turn.

All of these choices are much user-friendlier than `InputBox`.

Step through the code below with <kbd>F8</kbd> and study what it does.  Come back with questions if necessary but the more you can understand on your own the faster you will develop.

```
Option Explicit

' Please indent your macros consistently.  This makes them much easier ri read

Sub example()
  Dim Ran As Range
  Dim cnt As String

  Dim myarray() As String
  Dim ab As String

  ' Variables I have added or which are replacements for yours.
  Dim Answer As String
  Dim AllValuesGood As Boolean
  Dim InxMA As Long
  Dim InxSht As Long
  Dim Question As String

  ' I like to keep all my Dim statements together at the top.
  ' This makes them easier to find.
  Dim name, country, birth As String

  ' I have output to the Immediate window which is simpler when
  ' experimenting.
  'Open "D:\temp\test.txt" For Output As #1

  Question = "Enter your choice eg: ""1"" or ""1,2"""

  ' You omitted the code to check the Answer

  Do While True

    Answer = InputBox(Question, "Experiment with Input box")
    ' Have a string but user could have typed anything
    If Answer = "" Then
      ' Cannot tell if user has clicked Cancel or if user clicked Return
      ' before entering value.  Have to assume Cancel
      Debug.Print "User clicked Cancel"
      Exit Sub
    Else
      AllValuesGood = True     ' Assume good answer until find otherwise
      myarray = Split(Answer, ",")
      For InxMA = 0 To UBound(myarray)
        If IsNumeric(myarray(InxMA)) Then
          InxSht = Val(myarray(InxMA))
          If InxSht < 1 Or InxSht > 2 Then
            ' Sheet number outside permitted range
            AllValuesGood = False
            Exit For
          End If
        Else
          ' Non-numeric sheet number
          AllValuesGood = False
          'Debug.Assert False
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
    End If
    If AllValuesGood Then
      ' Have good answer.  Exit Do-Loop to print sheets
      Exit Do
    Else
      ' An invalid sheet number has been found
      Question = "Click cancel to exit or enter ""1"" or ""2"" or ""1, 2"""
      ' Loop to repeat Input
    End If

  Loop  ' Until have good answer

  ' If get here Answer is a list of good sheet number

  For InxMA = 0 To UBound(myarray)
    InxSht = Val(myarray(InxMA))
    ' I have not created sample worksheets with data in Z12, PQ26 and ab24
    ' but this shows the code you need
    'With Worksheets(InxSht)
    '  name = .Range("Z12").Value
    '  country = .Range("PQ26").Value
    '  birth = .Range("ab24").Value
    'Next
    name = "Name" & InxSht
    country = "Country" & InxSht
    birth = "Birth" & InxSht
    ' Have to initialise ab here because need new value per sheet
    ab = "this is sample data"
    ab = ab & name & country & birth
    Debug.Print ab
    ' The value of ab will be messy because you have no spaces between words.
    'Print #1, ab
  Next InxMA

End Sub
```

Comment: what is val in the programme

Comment: `Val` is a function.  If converts a number in string form to a number.  VBA will do automatic type conversions most of the time but I prefer to be explicit.

Comment: it is throwing me an error saying that sub or function not defined

Comment: From Microsoft Visual Basic Help: "Val Function.  Returns the numbers contained in a string as a numeric value of appropriate type."  I have just run the macro again and `Val` works as expected.  Try replacing `Val(myarray(InxMA))` by `myarray(InxMA)`.  On the top line click `Tools` then `References`. A list of available references will appear.  Which are ticked?

Comment: it worked i had declared val as string and used it elsewhere that was the reason..

Comment: I am pleased the cause of that problem has been found.  How useful is the rest of the routine?

Comment: Good.  Please accept the answer by clicking the outline tick at the top of the answer which will be helpful to both me and the site.